# Mongoose RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose as MongoDB ODM. Currently I've got problem with fetching documents with some criteria - Mongoose throws **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**.

I'm querying 1500+ documents and these documents have custom subdocuments.

Here is code:

```
  Customer.find({
      customerNonActiveBit: false,
      customerType: 0,
      customerBit: true
    })
    .where({priceLists: { $not: {$size: 0}}, customerContacts: { $not: {$size: 0}}})
    .exec()
    .then(customers => res.send(customers))
    .catch(err => {
      logger.error('Error while getting customers', err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    });
```

Here is customer schema:

```
var customerSchema = new Schema({
  name1: String,
  name2: String,
  customerId: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
  customerNonActiveBit: Boolean,
  customerType: Number,
  customerBit: Boolean,
  customerContacts: [{
    contactId: Number,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    number: String,
    sendPriceList: Boolean
  }],
  priceLists: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'PriceList'}]
});
```

I found some answers to this problem, but my case is slightly different.

Comment: The stack trace might provide a clue. Also, you're not using any custom [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)?

Comment: I'm not using any custom middleware. Stack trace doesn't say anything helpful. Node shows only winston common.js as a stack.

Comment: Try `console.log(err.stack)` before passing it to Winston.

Comment: could u figure it out? having same issue